# Array of references

Tags: wpf

I would like to have a DependencyPropery which is an array of referenced UIElements. In WPF we have the x:Array markup extension and also the x:Reference available but it can't get it working.

Any ideas on that?

Chris

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is in WPF is to assign the [UIElementCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection.aspx) class to your dependency property, like this:

```
public UIElementCollection ElementCollection
{
    get { return (UIElementCollection)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(UIElementCollection), typeof(MyClass), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

In the constructor of your class, you should set the dependency property to `new UIElementCollection`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on UIElementCollection!

Answer (score -1):

Just found the answer myself.

```
MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(UIElement[]), typeof(MyClass), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, MyPropertyChanged));
```

And the corresponding XAML looks like:

```
<cc:MyClass.MyProperty>
  <x:Array Type="UIElement">
    <x:Reference>NameOfTheReferencedUIElement</x:Reference>
  </x:Array>
</cc:MyClass.MyProperty>
```

This way the dependency property is automatically filled with an array of referenced UI objects in form of UIElements.

Chris

Comment: Are you sure this works with WPF? According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792007.aspx , x:Reference cannot be used with WPF.

Comment: Yes it does! see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx in WPF 4.0

Comment: @fmunkert: `x:Reference` is an exception, also the article does not state that it cannot be used, it just states that it won't work in compiled XAML.

Comment: It seems reasonable to expect this to work, in theory. But absent a valid, _complete_ code example that shows clearly the declaration in context, the above is not useful.